# How to convert a long to date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I have a long value in Rails, `134740800`, which is the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

How do I convert that to a date in `mm-dd-yyyy` format?

I figure the formatting would be done with something like `strftime` but I can't seem to find the right method to convert the long into a valid date.

Comment: sry meant seconds, Time.at was what I was looking for, thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
secs = 134740800/1000 # millisecs / 1000
t = Time.at(secs)
t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

Output

```
"01-02-1970"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s')
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean seconds since the epoch.

```
Time.at seconds_since_epoch
```

You can also pass a float. If you have milliseconds, divide by `1000.0` first.
You can then call `strftime` on the returned `Time` object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Time.at`:

```
irb(main):003:0> Time.at(134740800)
=> Tue Apr 09 08:00:00 -0400 1974
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an advisory... It's often a good idea to look at how fast some answers run. Here's a simple benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'date'

SECS = 134740800
LOOPS = 1_000_000

puts Time.at(SECS).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
puts Date.strptime(SECS.to_s, '%s').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

Benchmark.bm(14) do |x|
  x.report('Time.at:') { LOOPS.times { Time.at(SECS) }}
  x.report('Date.strptime:') { LOOPS.times { Date.strptime(SECS.to_s, '%s') }}
end
```

And the output is:

```
04-09-1974
04-09-1974
                     user     system      total        real
Time.at:         0.370000   0.020000   0.390000 (  0.392761)
Date.strptime:   6.320000   0.050000   6.370000 (  6.373248)
```